# Recently I downloaded ng - table and after a long search , the variable $ data - I can not format it

Tags: angularjs

Peace,
Recently I downloaded ng - table and after a long search , the variable `$data` - I can not format it ( he always left blank ) .
I leave here code I wrote , I'd love to answer!
Good Day!

[Link to code](https://plnkr.co/edit/eFh6GIK8Bpx5nwY3EcyO?p=catalogue)

Comment: add angularjs to your plunker, replace /getHousesPerUserUniq with json data and inside ngtableparams replace data: by dataset:

Comment: just found the answer, downloaded ng-table version 0.8 and it work thanks.